# Signing iOS app with Company account for Fabric

Tags: ios, google-fabric, code-signing-certificate

I'm developing an iOS app by using XCode9 and let XCode manage signing automatically.

[image]

When I archived the project, Fabric's Mac app asks me to distribute the new archive but still warns me about missing devices in my profile even I use a company account.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric and Crashlatics support distribution of your app in the Development mode.
So you have missed maybe  (which I have found is), your development certificate is not included the UDID of the Devices which you have mentioned in your distributing list, So Please be sure that the Devices UDID is contained in the certificate of your development certificate. (UDID : is the unique identifying key for the iOS Devices)

in Short : Apple Developer's certificate must have the devices registered there, and Should be included in the developing certificate.

Also I wanted to suggest you please be used " XCode manage signing automatically.". This is important.

**If you already added the devices UDID into your account**, then you must be using the production/Adhoc certificates for distribution. Please be used the development mode only.

Please let me know if you have any problem

Comment: As far as I know, I don't need to register device IDs when I use a company account...

Comment: it depends which developer account you have used, Generally Apple Developer individual and Organisation program needs to register the UDID whereas in the enterprise program, no need of it. See the Link attached. https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Yes. I think, this is the reason of my problem. Thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It only automates the signing but not the device registration unless you plug those iPhone devices to your mac with Xcode and it will ask you to automatically register the device. You can manually register the devices from the developer.apple.com. After that please download the updated adhoc profile.
.
.
.
Cheers,
Kel

Comment: As far as I know, I don't need to register device IDs when I use a company account...